# minimax algorithm optimization for connect 4

Tags: python, connect-four

I made a minimax algorithm for a connect 4 and I would like to optimize it to improve the calculation time.

I have already done the classic optimization such as alpha beta pruning and a variable where I store all the play already calculated so as not to recalculate them. I think there are still optimizations to be done but I can't find them.

my code (there may be some French word in it, sorry):

```py
def is_position_a_winner(board, none_pice, row, col=4, length_win=4):
    if type(row) in (list, tuple):
        length_win, col, row = col, row[1], row[0]
    item = board[row][col]
    rows = len(board)
    cols = len(board[0])
    if item == none_pice:
        return False
    for delta_row, delta_col in [(1,-1), (0,1), (1,1), (1,0)]:
        consecutive_items = 1
        for delta in (1, -1):
            delta_row *= delta
            delta_col *= delta
            next_row = row + delta_row
            next_col = col + delta_col
            while 0 <= next_row < rows and 0 <= next_col < cols:
                if board[next_row][next_col] == item:
                    consecutive_items += 1
                else:
                    break
                if consecutive_items == length_win:
                    return True
                next_row += delta_row
                next_col += delta_col
    return False

def is_full(board, none_pice=0):
    for row in board:
        for col in row:
            if col == none_pice:
                return False
    return True

def calc_piece_pos(col, board, none_pice=0):
    for row in range(5, -1, -1):
        if board[row][col] == none_pice:
            return (row, col)
    return False

def inverse(pice):
    if pice == 1: return 2
    if pice == 2: return 1

def mid(a,b):
    a1 = abs(a-3)
    b1 = abs(b-3)
    if a1 < b1:
        return a
    else:
        return b

def get_hash(board):
    return hash(tuple([tuple(i) for i in board]))

def load_save(board, lvl):
    try:
        return save[lvl][get_hash(board)]
    except KeyError:
        return None

def save_calcul(board, score, lvl):
    global save
    try:
        save[lvl][get_hash(board)] = score
    except KeyError:
        pass

test = [3,2,4,1,5,0,6]
def ia(board, pice, limit=6):
    global save
    save = [{} for _ in range(limit)]
    best_score = -100
    move = None
    for i in range(7):
        col = test[i]
        pos = calc_piece_pos(col, board)
        if pos:
            board[pos[0]][pos[1]] = pice
            score = mini_max(board, inverse(pice), limit-1, False, pos, -100, 100)
            board[pos[0]][pos[1]] = 0
            print(best_score, score, move, col)
            if score > best_score:
                best_score, move = score, col
            elif score == best_score:
                move = mid(move, col)
    return move

def mini_max(board, pice, limit, is_max, last_move, alpha, beta):
    global save
    load = load_save(board, limit)
    if load is not None:
        return load
    if is_position_a_winner(board, 0, last_move):
        score = -50 if is_max else 50
        save_calcul(board, score, limit)
        return score
    elif limit == 0 or is_full(board):
        save_calcul(board, 0, limit)
        return 0
    else:
        if is_max:
            best_score = -100
            for i in range(7):
                col = test[i]
                pos = calc_piece_pos(col, board)
                if pos:
                    board[pos[0]][pos[1]] = pice
                    score = mini_max(board, inverse(pice), limit-1, False, pos, alpha, beta)
                    if score != 0:
                        score -= (1 if score > 0 else -1)
                    board[pos[0]][pos[1]] = 0
                    best_score = max(score, best_score)
                    alpha = max(alpha, score)
                    if beta <= alpha:
                        break
            save_calcul(board, best_score, limit)
            return best_score

        else:
            best_score = 100
            for i in range(7):
                col = test[i]
                pos = calc_piece_pos(col, board)
                if pos:
                    board[pos[0]][pos[1]] = pice
                    score = mini_max(board, inverse(pice), limit-1, True, pos, alpha, beta)
                    if score != 0:
                        score -= (1 if score > 0 else -1)
                    board[pos[0]][pos[1]] = 0
                    best_score = min(score, best_score)
                    beta = min(beta, score)
                    if beta <= alpha:
                        break
            save_calcul(board, best_score, limit)
            return best_score

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import time
    board = [
        [0,0,0,2,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,2,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,1,2,0,0],
        [0,0,0,2,1,0,0],
        [0,0,2,1,1,0,0]
    ]
    board = [[0 for _ in range(7)] for _ in range(6)]
    t=time.monotonic()
    print(ia(board, 1, 14))
    print(time.monotonic()-t)
```